# Can't make Kivy buttons return their value

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy, kivy-language

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty
from kivy.uix.recycleview import RecycleView
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.core.window import Window
import sqlite3

#we give anime properties of name, studio, genre, year of release, we make a table with 1 column for the years, return values by SELECT * FROM anime WHERE year = x
#add a favorites screen to the app


try:
    conn = sqlite3.connect('database.db')
    cur = conn.cursor()

except:
    print('DB exists')

class MainWindow(Screen):
    def closure(self):
        conn.close()

    def table_a(self):
        cur.execute("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS anime(name text, original text, studio text, genre text, year integer)")

    def table_s(self):
        cur.execute("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS studio(id integer primary key, name text, founded integer)")

    def table_y(self):
        cur.execute("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS years(year integer)")

    def table_g(self):
        cur.execute("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS genre(id integer primary key, genre text)")

    def select(self, x):
        print(x)




class anime(Screen):

    def new(self, x):
        try:
            cur.execute("INSERT INTO anime VALUES (:name, :original, :studio, :genre, :year)",
                        {"name": x[0], "original": x[1], "studio": x[2], "genre": x[3], "year": int(x[4])})
            conn.commit()
            #for row in cur.execute("SELECT * FROM anime"):
            #    print(row)
        except:
            print("no values")

    def butts(self):
        lis = cur.execute("SELECT * FROM anime")
        l = []
        li = []
        for i in lis:
            l.append(list(i))

        for i in l:
            z = Button(text=str(i[0]), on_press=lambda x: MainWindow.select(None, i[0]))
            yield z


    def lily(self, x):
        return [x.add_widget(i) for i in self.butts()]

    def err(self):
        print("something went to shit")



class studio(Screen):

    def new(self, x):
        try:
            cur.execute("INSERT INTO studio VALUES (:id, :name, :founded)",
                        {"id": None, "name": x[0], "founded": x[1]})
            conn.commit()
            for row in cur.execute("SELECT * FROM studio"):
                print(row)
        except:
            print("no values")

    def butts(self, x):
        try:
            lis = ['a', 'a', 'a', 'a', '0', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', '0', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', '0', 'a', 'a']
            return [x.add_widget(Button(text=str(i[0]))) for i in lis]
        except:
            pass

    def err(self):
        print("something went to shit")

class years(Screen):

    try:
        def butts(self, x):
            try:
                lis = ['a', 'a', 'a', 'a', '0', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', '0', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', '0', 'a', 'a']
                return [x.add_widget(Button(text=str(i[0]))) for i in lis]
            except:
                pass
    except:
        pass

class genre(Screen):

    try:
        def butts(self, x):
            try:
                lis = ['a', 'a', 'a', 'a', '0', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', '0', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', '0', 'a', 'a']
                return [x.add_widget(Button(text=str(i[0]))) for i in lis]
            except:
                pass
    except:
        pass

class yearly(Screen):

    lis = [("no", "noo", "nooo"), ("no", "noo", "nooo"), ("no", "noo", "nooo"),
           ("no", "noo", "nooo")]


class WindowManager(ScreenManager):
    pass

kv = Builder.load_file("project.kv")

class ProjectApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return kv

if __name__ == '__main__':
    ProjectApp().run()
```

```
#:import Button kivy.uix.button.Button

WindowManager:
    MainWindow:
    anime:
    studio:
    years:
    genre:
    yearly:

<MainWindow>:
    name: "menu"

    GridLayout:
        cols: 1
        size_hint: 0.3, 1


        Button:
            text: "Anime"
            on_release:
                root.table_a()
                app.root.current = "anime"
                root.manager.transition.direction = "left"

        Button:
            text: "Studio"
            on_release:
                root.table_s()
                app.root.current = "studio"
                root.manager.transition.direction = "left"

        Button:
            text: "Godine"
            on_release:
                root.table_y()
                app.root.current = "years"
                root.manager.transition.direction = "left"

        Button:
            text: "Žanrovi"
            on_release:
                root.table_g()
                app.root.current = "genre"
                root.manager.transition.direction = "left"

        Button:
            text: "Po godinama"
            on_release:
                app.root.current = "yearly"
                root.manager.transition.direction = "left"

        Button:
            text: "Exit"
            on_release:
                app.stop()
                root.closure()

<anime>:
    name: "anime"


    GridLayout:
        cols: 2

        BoxLayout:
            id: Scroll
            orientation: 'vertical'
            spacing: 0.01
            cols: 1
            on_kv_post: root.lily(Scroll)

        GridLayout:
            cols: 1
            rows: 2

            GridLayout:
                cols: 2
                rows: 5
                spacing: 10
                padding: [10, 0, 10, 0]

                Label:
                    text: "Ime"

                TextInput:
                    id: ime

                Label:
                    text: "Original"

                TextInput:
                    id: og

                Label:
                    text: "Studio"

                TextInput:
                    id: studio

                Label:
                    text: "Žanr"

                TextInput:
                    id: genre

                Label:
                    text: "Godina"

                TextInput:
                    id: godina

            GridLayout:
                cols: 4
                rows: 1
                spacing: 10
                padding: [10, 50, 10, 50]

                Button:
                    text: "Novi"
                    on_release:
                        root.new([ime.text, og.text, studio.text, genre.text, godina.text])
                        root.lily(Scroll)



                Button:
                    text: "Spremi"



                Button:
                    text: "Obriši"


                Button:
                    text: "Go back"
                    on_release:
                        app.root.current = "menu"
                        root.manager.transition.direction = "right"


<studio>:
    name: "studio"

    GridLayout:
        cols: 2

        BoxLayout:
            id: Scroll
            orientation: 'vertical'
            spacing: 0.01
            cols: 1
            on_kv_post:
                root.butts(Scroll)

        GridLayout:
            cols: 1
            rows: 2

            GridLayout:
                cols: 2
                rows: 3

                Label:
                    text: "Studio"

                TextInput:
                    id: studio

                Label:
                    text: "Godina osnivanja"

                TextInput:
                    id: godina

            GridLayout:
                cols: 4
                rows: 1

                Button:
                    text: "Novi"
                    on_release:
                        root.new((studio.text, godina.text))


                Button:
                    text: "Spremi"


                Button:
                    text: "Obriši"


                Button:
                    text: "Go back"
                    on_release:
                        app.root.current = "menu"
                        root.manager.transition.direction = "right"

<years>:
    name: "years"

    GridLayout:
        cols: 2

        BoxLayout:
            id: Scroll
            orientation: 'vertical'
            spacing: 0.01
            cols: 1
            on_kv_post:
                root.butts(Scroll)

        GridLayout:
            cols: 1
            rows: 2

            GridLayout:
                cols: 2
                rows: 1

                Label:
                    text: "Godina"

                TextInput:
                    name: "godina"

            GridLayout:
                cols: 4
                rows: 1

                Button:
                    text: "Novi"


                Button:
                    text: "Spremi"


                Button:
                    text: "Obriši"


                Button:
                    text: "Go back"
                    on_release:
                        app.root.current = "menu"
                        root.manager.transition.direction = "right"

<genre>:
    name: "genre"

    GridLayout:
        cols: 2

        BoxLayout:
            id: Scroll
            orientation: 'vertical'
            spacing: 0.01
            cols: 1
            on_kv_post:
                root.butts(Scroll)

        GridLayout:
            cols: 1
            rows: 2

            GridLayout:
                cols: 2
                rows: 1

                Label:
                    text: "Žanr"

                TextInput:
                    name: "genre"

            GridLayout:
                cols: 4
                rows: 1

                Button:
                    text: "Novi"


                Button:
                    text: "Spremi"


                Button:
                    text: "Obriši"


                Button:
                    text: "Go back"
                    on_release:
                        app.root.current = "menu"
                        root.manager.transition.direction = "right"

<yearly>:
    name: "yearly"

    GridLayout:
        cols: 4

        GridLayout:
            cols: 1
            rows: 2

            Button:
                text: "Novi"


            Button:
                text: "Spremi"

        ScrollView:
            GridLayout:
                rows: 1000
                cols: 1
                on_kv_post: [self.add_widget(Button(text=str(i[0]))) for i in root.lis]

        GridLayout:
            cols: 1
            rows: 3

            Button:
                text: "Novi"



            Button:
                text: "Spremi"

            Button:
                text: "Go back"
                on_release:
                    app.root.current = "menu"
                    root.manager.transition.direction = "right"

        ScrollView:
            GridLayout:
                rows: 1000
                cols: 1
                on_kv_post: [self.add_widget(Button(text=str(i[0]))) for i in root.lis]
```

The buttons created in the "anime" class do not return their value when pressed. When I make changes, it ends in 3 ways: 1. I get them all to return the value of the very last button, 2. they do nothing, 3. I get an error

I have tried numerous suggestions from the internet, but to no avail. Please help, I have been struggling with this for over a week at this point.

Answer (score 0):

That is a common problem when defining a `lambda` fuction that uses a loop variable. Since `lambda` functions are not evaluated until they are actually called, you end up with the loop variable always evaluated as the last value of the loop variable. A fix is to replace:

```
z = Button(text=str(i[0]), on_press=lambda x: MainWindow.select(None, i[0]))
```

with:

```
z = Button(text=str(i[0]), on_press=lambda x, j=i: MainWindow.select(None, j[0]))
```

this forces the evaluation of `j` during the loop.